# Local transaction concept understanding

Tags: java, jta

As said in `Open/XA` spec

> A global transaction (also called a distributed transaction) enlists
>   more than one resource in the transaction.

But I have a question about a local transactnio. JSR 907 JTA 1.2 defines the local transaction as follows:

> Local transactions are transactions that are started and coordinated
>   by the resource manager internally. The XAResource interface is not
>   used for local transactions.

That's the local transaction also can enlist more than one resource in the transaction. The only difference is in implementation, is it?